# FB ui not works

Tags: facebook

I am using the below code for initializing the fb ui:

```
<script>



window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '123555029137905', status: true, cookie: true,

                xfbml: true

            });
        };

 FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: Title,
                    link: 'http://google.com/',
                    caption: 'google.com',
                    description: Body,
                    picture: path,
                    message: 'abc'
                }, function (response) {
                    if (response.post_id) {
                        bootbox.alert('Your milestone has been shared');
                    }
                });

</script>
```

This Code works well.But sometimes it gives error when I click button on the page to open the FB ui: http://prntscr.com/a82jp9

When I look closer to it then what I discover is that it doesn't have app id in the url.So ,can anybody suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Are you calling `FB.ui` directly? Could be a timing issue. Try calling it when the user clicks a link or button instead.

Comment: the Fb ui is called on the button click.

Comment: So the code you have shown is not your _actual_ code (please at least mention this in the future.) Then the reason for the error is likely that the SDK has not been initialized when the user clicks the button. So disable the button, and enable it from within the `fbAsyncInit` function.

Comment: Could you please write here what you are trying to say.If possible?

Comment: I did write what I was trying to say. (Otherwise, I would have written something else.) Do you have a specific question on how to implement it? Then start by doing some basic research please.